# Why does dynamically added content to a registered and dequeued UITableViewCell persist from one use of the cell to another?

Tags: objective-c, ios, uitableview

First the UITableViewCell is registered for reuse like this

```
UINib *cellLoader=[UINib nibWithNibName:@"GroupCell_iPhone" bundle:nil];
[self.tableView registerNib:cellLoader forCellReuseIdentifier:@"GroupCell"];
```

then in the cellForRowAtIndexPath delegate

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
```

the cell is dequeued

```
GroupCell_iPhone *cell=(GroupCell_iPhone*)[self.tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"GroupCell"];
```

then a series of UILabel and other objects are created dynamically based upon a series of criteria and added to the cell like this

```
[cell.contentView addSubview:noActivityLabel];
```

The problem arises when the second and subsequent cells are dequeued and appear to have the dynamically added objects from the first dequeued cell. In the end, every cell will be different. Is the dequeued cell a "pointer" to one instance of the UITableViewCell? Why do these subsequently dequeued cells have the content from the first?

If this is the case what is the best approach to creating cells w/ dynamic/changing content? Should a new instance of the cell be created each time? Can the dequeued cell be "cloned"?

Clarification:
All cells in the table start w/ a base layout but then unique content is added to each cell based upon some data associated w/ that cell. Therefore, every cell in the table is unique, i.e., there are different subviews (UILable, UIImageView, etc.) in the cells.

Answer (score 0):

**Why do these subsequently dequeued cells have the content from the
 first?**

Instead of re-creating each time new cells, it his far better to re-use your already created cells who are not longer displayed. This is what actually do your tableView when dequeueing your cells: it give you some non-displayed cells if it can.

Say you need to display a tableview with 1000 cells, and the tableView is actually showing only 6 cells at a time. Instead of creating 1000 cells, it will re-use the cells stacks so that it doesn't need to re-create new one.

**Is the dequeued cell a "pointer" to one instance of the
UITableViewCell? Why do these subsequently dequeued cells have the
content from the first?**

Because it's the same pointer object, so it will have the same content as it was at the first display. You need then to update its data.

**Should a new instance of the cell be created each time? Can the
dequeued cell be "cloned"?**

You only need to create new cell, when

```
[self.tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"GroupCell"]
```

return nothing. Here's a simple example:

```
 - (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
 // get your cell from the stack    
GroupCell_iPhone *cell=(GroupCell_iPhone*)[self.tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"GroupCell"];

 // or create new one if nil. Note: you must give it the same identifier than the
 // one you are using for the dequeue. Or tableview will not be able to return you anything from the dequeing.
if(!cell)
 cell = [GroupCell_iPhone newWithIdentifier: @"GroupCell"] + autorelease];
```

** update**

```
// here you are sure to have a valid cell, so you can display content according to the indexPath
// display: use a controller who will update your cell change
// note, the first method clean what was inside your cell. You can keep the subview and reuse them the same way as tableview do.
    [myDisplayClassCellController emptyCellSubview: cell];

// here you add all the display logic you want into your cell view. Note, you need indexPath
// because you need to display depending of the stack.
    [myDisplayClassCellController decorateCellWithCustomViews: cell atIndexPath: indexPath];
```

** end update**

```
// then you can return back the cell to the tableView
return cell;
}
```

Comment: What's different from your example is the number and type of subviews in the cell is dynamic. In your sample you dequeue the cell and just change the value of "label.text". However, my situation calls for dynamically adding different subviews to the cell which are driven dynamically based upon data associated w/ each individual cell. Do you have any suggestions related to the dynamic addition of subviews to a cell.

Comment: My example was simple in order to keep the things clears. If all of your cells contain an added custom subview, the philosophy is still the same: you add a subview when creating the content, you update the view content when the cell already created need update. You can create a class specifically in order to handle these change. I have updated my example

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if it is the best way but I have done the following:

Created a CustomCellClass with several subclasses: CustomCellType1, CustomCellType2 Custom CellType3 etc. Where the CustomCellSubclasses all use different parts of the Same Model to Display information.

Then, I can add give CustomCellClass a prePareDataForCell function that sets some basic attributes. If the CustomCellSubclass needs them it has them, if not things move along just the same (I think, this is the part I am not sure if it is good practice or not).

Then I can do some pseudocode like this:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    CustomCellClass *returnCell = (CustomCellClass*)[tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
    MyObject *obj = [self.fetchedResultsController objectAtIndexPath:indexPath];

    if ([returnCell.reuseIdentifier isEqualToString:CustomCellType1) {
        CustomCellType1 *cell = (CustomCellType1*)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CustomCellType1];

        if (!cell) {
            cell = [[CustomCellType1 alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CustomCellType1];
            NSArray *topLevelObjects = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"CustomCellType1" owner:self options:nil];
            cell = [topLevelObjects objectAtIndex:0];
        }
        // This is a basic cell doesn't need anything special done with the object model
        returnCell = cell;
    } else if ([[returnCell reuseIdentifier] isEqualToString:CustomCellType2]) {
        CustomCellType2 *cell = (CustomCellType2 *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CustomCellType2];

        if (!cell) {
            cell = [[CustomCellType2 alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CustomCellType2];
            NSArray *topLevelObjects = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"CustomCellType2" owner:self options:nil];
            cell = [topLevelObjects objectAtIndex:0];
        }
        // Do stuff with obj data only needed for this type of cell, perhaps modify the cells subviews
        [cell preConfigureCustomCellType2:obj];
        returnCell = cell;
    } else {
        CustomCellType3 *cell = (CustomCellType3*)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:StandardMailCell];

        if (!cell) {
            cell = [[CustomCellType3 alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:StandardMailCell];
            NSArray *topLevelObjects = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"CustomCellType3" owner:self options:nil];
            cell = [topLevelObjects objectAtIndex:0];
        }
        // Do stuff with obj data only needed for this type of cell perhaps modify the same subviews in a different way for this type of cell
        [cell preConfigureCustomCellType3:mail];
        returnCell = cell;
    }

    if (![tableView isDragging] && !tableView.decelerating) {
             // I used this to only run an expensive operation after the the customer flicks and the table comes to a rest.
    }

    return returnCell;
}
```

Comment: Thanks. The challenge is no two cells content is the same. I am pursuing a different approach of making each cell a section and then inserting rows based upon the data instead of trying to put everything in one cell.